# Loopback3 and Swagger Connector: Error loading swagger file

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to create an api model from a swagger file (`my-api.json`) using Loopback's [Swagger connector](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Swagger-connector.html) (assuming that's what this connector is for!).

However, when running the [loopback-cli](https://loopback.io), I get the following error:

```js
? Enter the swagger spec url or file path: my-api.json
Loading my-api.json...
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '$ref' of null
    at C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\generator-loopback\swagger\spec-loader.js:124:13
    at baseClone (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2641:27)
    at C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2711:34
    at arrayEach (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:516:11)
    at baseClone (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2705:7)
    at C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2711:34
    at arrayEach (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:516:11)
    at baseClone (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:2705:7)
    at Function.cloneDeepWith (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:11120:14)
    at parseSpec (C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\generator-loopback\swagger\spec-loader.js:123:19)
    at C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\generator-loopback\swagger\spec-loader.js:160:5
    at C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\loopback-cli\node_modules\generator-loopback\swagger\spec-loader.js:86:11
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

Here's the `my-api-json` swagger file:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "my description",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "title": "my title",
    "termsOfService": "TBD",
    "contact": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "url": "http://www.myname.com",
      "email": "johndoe@aol.com"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "TBD",
      "url": "http://www.myname.com"
    },
    "x-classificationRecord": "Classsification of this swagger file - APPROVED"
  },
  "basePath": "/myPath",
  "schemes": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "AdminSecurity": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "in": "query",
      "name": "apikey"
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "/admin/vcap": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "security": [
          {
            "AdminSecurity": []
          }
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "misc_info_controller",
        "operationId": "getVCAP",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTopicEntity": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTopicEntity",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTopic": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTopic",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllEntityFacets": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllEntityFacets",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTopicEntityFacets": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTopicEntityFacets",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTopicEntityRelation": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTopicEntityRelation",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTopicPropertyFacet": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTopicPropertyFacet",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAllTable13": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAllTable13",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblComponentType": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblComponentType",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblElement": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblElement",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblFeature": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblFeature",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblSymbolPlacementInst": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblSymbolPlacementInst",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblSymbolElementLink": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblSymbolElementLink",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/getAlltblSymol": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "getAlltblSymol",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/query/newQuery": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "database"
        ],
        "x-swagger-router-controller": "db",
        "operationId": "newQuery",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Generic": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "GenericError": {
      "required": [
        "status",
        "statusCode",
        "error"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Status indicating there was an error, should always be error",
          "enum": [
            "error"
          ]
        },
        "statusCode": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "HTTP Status Code for the error"
        },
        "error": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "String indicating what the error was"
        },
        "trace": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Original Error Message providing more detail if available"
        }
      }
    },
    "ErrorResponse": {
      "required": [
        "code",
        "message"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any tips on how to fix? Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the my-api.json file as well so we can see if there is something wrong with the format?

Comment: @sashi added the swagger spec file. Thankyou!